# The Pappus Line

Tags: projective-geometry

The text which is unclear to me:

---

Let the range of points $(A_i)$ be projectively related to the range of points $(B_i)$ under the correspondence $A_i \leftrightarrow B_i$. Fix $i$: then the pencil of lines through $A_i$ is projectively related to the pencil of lines through $B_i$ by the sequence:
$$(A_iB_j){\overset{A_i}{\wedge}}B_j\wedge A_j {\overset{B_i}{\wedge}}(B_iA_j)$$
The line $(A_i B_i)$ is self-corresponding and so this projectivity is a perspectivity from a line $c_i$. If we interchange the role of $i$ and $j$ we see that $c_i$ is independent of $i$. This line is called the Pappus line of the projectivity. It has the following property: the intersection of $A_iB_j$ with $A_jB_i$ lies on the Pappus line. In fact once the Pappus line is known then it can be used as an alternative geometric construction of the point $B$ corresponding to $A$.

---

It's a paragraph from a [book on geometry (Roger Fenn geometry), section "Projectivities and Perspectivities"](https://archive.org/details/geometry0000fenn/page/194/mode/2up?view=theater)

Here are my questions:

1. a) How the **line** $(A_iB_i)$ can be self-correspondent?(self-correspondent line is not defined before. But self-correspondent point is: it's a point which corresponds to itself after composition of perspectives). b) What is a self-correspondent line and how to imagine/draw it?
2. The notation $(A_iB_j){\overset{A_i}{\wedge}}B_j\wedge A_j {\overset{B_i}{\wedge}}(B_iA_j)$ itself. I even can't understand what it means as it is not defined earlier in this book. Notations $(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4){\overset{O}{\wedge}}(B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4)$ and $(A){\overset{O}{\wedge}}(B)$ are defined, however and clear to me.
3. What is a perspectivity from a line? Where it arises from?(it is not defined as well earlier). How to imagine draw it?
4. Finally, what the points $A$ and $B$ are? Is it $(A_i) = (A_1, A_2, A_3, A)$ and $(B_i) = (B_1, B_2, B_3, B)$ in the very beginning, so $A$ and $B$ are 4th points, or, $A$ and $B$ are just some abstract points where given a Pappus line and some $A$ we can construct corresponding $B$?

Edit: what adds mess is it's not mentioned which plane is used for this  proof - Projective or Euclidean. In case Projective is used, then, maybe, I have to consider duality, but I'm not sure...

P.S. I googled for it, no results. As everywhere Pappus theorem is being proved without introducing notation above.

P.P.S. if the notation is a complete mess, then just let me know please. So I'll give up with this very construction. I can't tell if it is, as i'm not too proficient in projective geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Perspectivity from a line" is the dual of the "perspectivity from a point":
The perspectivity of the set of lines through point $P$ to the set of lines through point $Q$ from the line $l$ maps any line $p$ through $P$ to the line of $p\cap l$ and $Q$.

A projectivity from a set of lines through a point to the set of lines through another point is a composition of countable perspectivities from lines - so it is just the dual of projectivities among lines.

We can also define a perspectivity from a set of lines through a point to a line. If $l$ is a line and $P$ is a point, we just map any line $p$ through $P$ to $p\cap l$.

So the construction is as follows:

- A projectivity $\pi$ is given from a line $e$ to a line $f$.
- We fix a point $A_i$ on the line $e$ and another point $B_i$ on line $f$.
- We construct the following projectivity from the set of lines through $A_i$ to the set of lines through $B_i$:

  1. we consider a line $a$ through $A_i$ and let its intersection with $f$ be $B_j$.
  2. $\pi^{-1}$ maps $B_j$ to $A_j$.
  3. Then the image of $a=A_iB_j$ is $B_jA_i$.
     This is a projectivity indeed, since it is a finite composition of projectivities.
- The above projectivity maps $A_iB_i$ to itself, so it is called a self-correspondent element.
- It is known that if a projectivity among the sets of lines through two point maps the line of the two points to itself (i.e. it is self-correspondent), then the projecitivity is just a perspectivity from a line. It is the dual of a well-known statement for projectivities among lines. Now this line is denoted by $c_i$ and called the Pappos-line.
- In the above construction if we interchange the roles of $A_i$ and $B_i$ with $A_j$ and $B_j$ we get the same line $c_i$.
- $A$ is just an arbitrary point of line $e$ and $B$ is the image of $A$ under $\pi$. So the last statement is that we can use the Pappos line to construct the image of any point on $e$ under the projectivity $\pi$ if the images of three points are given.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit 1) on "Then the image of $a=A_i B_j$ is $B_j A_i$". This image is possible only if there exist a line through $A_i B_j \cap B_i A_j$ and a point of $A_i B_i$.(a line containing these 4 points). But we don't know if there exists such a line beforehand. 2) on "This is a projectivity indeed, since it is a finite composition of projectivities". What you mean by "This" - is it a projectivity between pencil of lines through $A_i$ and pencil of lines of $B_i$ for fixed $i$? 3) finite composition of which projectivities?(i just don't see them)

Comment: 4) if there exist a line through $A_i B_j \cap B_i A_j$ and a point of $A_i B_i$ and we call it $c_i$, what you mean by "interchange the roles of $A_i$ and $B_i$ with $A_j$ and $B_j$ - consider next pairs of A and B for other fixed $i$'s ? 5) how we get the same line $c_i$ - it's not obvious at all that we'll get the very same line for all of 4 pairs of A and B ( $A_i$ and $B_i$, $i$=1..4) - why we will get the same line?(I see only some coinciding points, but not entire lines)

Comment: 1) It is a typo: the image of $a=A_iB_j$ is $B_iA_j$.
2) Yes, we constructed a projecivity from the pencil of lines through $A_i$ to the pencil of lines through $B_i$ for fixed $i$.
3) It is the composition of the following projectivities:
- the perspectivity which maps any line through $A_i$ to its intersection with $f$
- $\pi^{-1}$
- the perspectivity which maps any point on $e$ to the line though this point and $B_i$
4) Yes, if we fix $A_j$ and $B_j$, and $A_i$ and $B_i$ play the role of the arbitrary other point - I mean this by "interchangin the role".

Comment: 5) $e_i$ always contains the images of $e\cap f$ under $\pi$ and $\pi^{-1}$, independently of the choice of $A_i$ and $B_i$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanations! Now everything is clear to me except (5). Using construction $(A_iB_j){\overset{A_i}{\wedge}}B_j\wedge A_j {\overset{B_i}{\wedge}}(B_iA_j)$ we get $(A_iB_i)$ invariant under some line $c_i$. But this line does depend on i: for each pair of A & B we'll get a different line. Why those $c_i$ lines are the same? Sorry, I didn't get your last comment about (5) as you refer $e_i$ there, which is not defined yet. And as for multiple images of $e \cap f$ - I'm lost at this point completely. I do not have a degree in maths. If i had, I wouldn't ask this question :)

Comment: From the above construction $c_i$ is a line where all points $A_iB_j\cap A_jB_i$ lie for a fixed $i$ (and $A_j$ is an arbitrary point of $e$ and its image under $\pi$ is $B_j$).
Let us denote $e\cap f$ by $I$.
First, choose $A_j:= I$. Then $A_jB_i=f$, $B_j=\pi(I)$ and thus $A_iB_j\cap A_jB_i=A_i\pi(I)\cap f=\pi(I)$.
Next, choose $A_j:=\pi^{-1}(I)$. Then $B_j=I$, thus $A_iB_j=e$, so $A_iB_j\cap A_jB_i=e\cap \pi^{-1}(I)B_i=\pi^{-1}(I)$.
So we get that - independently of the choice of $A_i$ - $e_i$ is the line through $\pi(I)$ and $\pi^{-1}(I)$.It only depends on the given projectivity $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarifications! Without them, it's near to impossible to understand that paragraph from the book(at least for a person, who learns on his/her own). I'll take in braces the most subtle things you helped me with. 
Projectivity we construct for fixed $i$
[turns out to be perspectivity from a line between pencils $A_i B_j$ and $B_i A_j$
and it may be perspectivity only if all points $A_i B_j \cap B_i A_j$ lay on the same line
Then it turns out that this line always passes through $\pi(I)$ and $\pi^{-1}(I)$, regardless of $i$, that is the line is the same for all $i$]